# Want to know the exact comment

Tags: java, jar

how to run a jar file in background in windows cmd

this below jar file cmd i want to run in background

java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts_appedo_agent-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -jar appedo_tomcat_agent_2.0.063.jar

Comment: Just add to your question what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a platform-independent manner.

In Unix/Linux, you would call the `fork()` system call, which duplicates your process. With Java, that means duplicating the entire JVM. Then, you'd have to figure out whether it's the parent process or the child process, which you can determine from the process ID that the `fork()` call gives you. If it's the parent process, you exit. If it's the child process, you have to close standard input, standard output and standard error.

In Windows, there appears to be the `FreeConsole` function, but I know next to nothing about Windows programming.

So conceivably, you could write a JNA library that figures out on which platform you are, and invokes the appropriate calls to achieve this. But it's probably not the best idea to get rid of the console window when starting a Java application.

Answer (score 0):

Use `javaw`, although you won't get any console output either, which is inconvenient.